# How to avoid hardcoding URLs (or Routes) in AngularJS ? (provide URL resolution)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

As I am in learning phase of AngularJS, today I noticed one thing about the tutorials avaliable for it.

In the tutorials, **the URLs used are hardcoded in the HTML and JS** files.

For example:
If I have **my routes** defined like this in my config:

```
// config.js        
$routeProvider.when("/", {          // Home Page
                templateUrl: basePageUrl,
                controller: "Home"
            }).when("/searches", {
                templateUrl: basePageUrl,   // Search Page
                controller: "SearchPage",
            })
```

Now in my **home.html** , if I want to create a link to searches page. I have to do the following:

```
<!-- home.html -->
<div>
  Hello Home
  <p> Go to <a href="#/searches">Searches</a> </p>  <!-- I had to hard code the link -->
</div>
```

So, I was **looking for a solution** so I **don't have to hard-code** the links in HTML or JS files.

More like, the **urls resolution** functionality that each Backend MVC framework provides.. e.g

1. Django: `{% url %}` templetag for HTML and `reverse()` for python code
2. Rails: `<%= link_to %>` tag for HTML etc..

**Is there a URL resolution functionality provided by AngularJS or any plugin ?**

Note: I can implement something similar by storing JS variables/object for urls, but that doesn't look a good design to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use UI-Router for this.  It has named 'states' instead of hardcoded urls

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

In your case you could use:

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: "/",
    templateUrl: "partials/home.html",
    controller: 'HomeController'
  })
  .state('searches', {
    url: "/searches",
    templateUrl: "partials/searches.html",
    controller: 'SeachController'
  });
```

And then reference it in your template as

```
<a ui-sref="searches">Searches</a>
```

This comes in handy when you want to handle more complicated urls

```
.state('book', {
  url: '/books/:bookID/',
  templateUrl: 'partials/book-detail.html',
  controller: 'BookController'
})
```

Link in a template

```
<a ui-sref="book({ bookID: book.id })">{{ book.title }}</a>
```

You can then access `bookID` in your controller using `$stateParams.bookID`